# How to search skype chat history for linux beta version

Tags: kubuntu, skype

How can I search within skype chat history?

I tried CTRL+F but nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Beta has been released already.

Comment: Its beta, sorry

Answer (score 2):

According to [Skype community](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-linux-alpha-1-5-0-3-no-search-function/td-p/4457927):

> Search in conversations is not yet supported in the Alpha Preview of
>   Skype for Linux.

Comment: It says beta :)

Comment: This link is no longer working..

Comment: still no option to search skype history, this program SUCKS!

Comment: @AryehArmon Stick to Skype classic. There it works. I am using version 4.3.0.37.

Comment: Still no search option. Wow, that's bad. Good thing I keep Skype linux 4.x around for such times since the beta version is supposed to have these sort of issues.

Comment: I used to think that Skype linux was pretty bad software, then I tried Skype linux 5.x LOL

Comment: Try now skype preview, it's totally dumbed down, no more favourites!

Comment: it's 2018 and I'm using version 8.33, it still has no chat logs for older messages.... What kind of software lobotomizes users???  It sucks...